# Script for emptying a specific subfolder in a projecttree

Tags: python, for-loop, scripting, robocopy, forfiles

We have a networkshare with approximately ~3000 projectfolders. The naming convention is like following:

Projects created in 2018: 2018xxx 
Projects created in 2019: 2019xxx

All these projectfolders have the same set of subfolders, for example:

01 Folder 1
02 Folder 2
03 Folder 3
04 Temporary

What I want to create is a scheduled script (or anything else) to delete all files **older than 7 days** in the ***04 Temporary*** folder in each projectfolder starting with ***2020xxx***

What would be the best way?

Best regards.

Comment: Check out the two libraries of Python : https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html#basic-use and https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html# You can use regex for your file names to delete.

Comment: Did you try anything? Should be an quiet easy task with python: Loop through all the folders, remember those who start with 2020, then check all files in the temp folder in those folders and loop through all files. Then delete those files who haven't been modified in the last 7 days by using `os.stat(filename).st_mtime`.